# How can I remove spaces before commas in python without regexes?

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

```py
print(contact.lastname,",", contact.firstname,",", contact.email,",", contact.phone)
```

The output is:

```
Polo , Marco , cam.com , 444-444-4444
```

I want:

```
Polo, Marco, cam.com, 444-444-4444
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string.replace(" ,",",")
```

You can use the replace method to substitute `" ,"` with `","` and then you have what you want.

Although, with your example, just do:

```
print(contact.lastname+",",contact.firstname+",",contact.email+",",contact.phone)
```

When you do `print(v,w)` you automatically add a space. So if you do `print(v,",",w)` you have the space you try to get rid of. If, instead, you do `print(v+",")` then you have no space between the text in v and the comma.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string format :

```
print(f"{contact.lastname},{contact.firstname},{contact.email},{contact.phone}")
```

Or if you want to keep multiple parameters in the `print` funciton, use the `sep` (separator) parameter :

```
print(a, b, c, sep=',')
```

Comment: `print(contact.lastname, contact.firstname, contact.email, contact.phone, sep=', ')`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, of course this is a better way to do